# Need for cold wallet instructions instead of an external link

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/42/136) is an important one for which I think a detailed answer needs to be on Stack Exchange itself. The [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/43/136) links to a thorough but external [guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/48cgmd/an_extensive_guide_for_securely_generating_an/)

> But for an actual, detailed response, instead of copy/pasting someone else's guide entirely, I'll refer you to the extensive guide from one of our more fantastic community members, dEBRUYNE

Should dEBRUYNE  himself or someone else answer this answer on Stack Exchange? I think having a detailed answer would be preferable to a link to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think having a detailed answer would be preferable to a link to one.

I agree. If someone wants to reformat it such that it fits that Stack Exchange, go ahead :) Otherwise I'll do it in the foreseeable future.